# Automatically Fetch Branch, Run Script, and Push to Other Branch

Tags: git, github-api

I would like to automatically copy from the `develop` branch to a second branch, let's call it `clean`, whenever I update the first branch `develop`. All new and changed `.py` files in the `clean` branch are then to be processed by the script [autopep8](https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8) and pushed.

I figured that I could maybe use GitHub's [webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) to listen for events on a specific branch, but I am not sure how to deploy the script.

Is this this the right way to approach the problem or is there an easier way to automatize the style-based cleaning version? My goal is to keep a dirty version with commented-out code and custom quirks, while delivering a clean version - to be tested separately.

> “I choose a lazy person to do a hard job. Because a lazy person will
>   find an easy way to do it.” —Bill Gates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly could do this using webhooks and the GitHub API, but I feel that using [Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) might be a more efficient way of approaching the problem. The only issue with doing it this way is that you will be required to add the hook into any new clone of the repo, as hooks are not shared between clones.